# Return something after revert in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to do a function in solidity that if there aren't any problem it will return true, but if there are it returns false. Also, I want to indicate what what the problem that caused the transaction couldn't be completed.
With require I can't do it because I can't return false or true depending the case. And with revert it doesn't work either.
Is there any way of doing this?

PD: I also try events, and registering the error, but with events, the transaction ends correctly.

With events I tried this, but like I've said the transaction ends correctly but return false and in the logs it's posible to see the error

```
function example(address user) public returns(bool){
        
        if(condition1){
            emit Error("ERROR 1");
            return false;
        }

        
        if(condition2){
            emit Error("ERROR 2");
            return false;
        }


        // DO SOMETHING

        return true;
    }
```

With require I tried this, but it returns true even though the transaction doesn't end correctly

```
function example(address user) public returns(bool){
        
        require(condition1, "ERROR1");

        require(condition2, "ERROR2");


        // DO SOMETHING

        return true;
    }
```

With revert I'd tried this, like in the require it returns true and teh transaction doesn't end correctly

```
function example(address user) public returns(bool){
        
        if(condition1){
            revert("ERROR 1");
            return false;
        }

        
        if(condition2){
            revert("ERROR 2");
            return false;
        }


        // DO SOMETHING

        return true;
    }
```

What I want it's to return false and also I want the transaction doesn't end correctly. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a value and revert the transaction at the same time because in the first case you are indicating the call was successful and, in the second, you are raising an exception that, unless caught in a `try/catch` statement by a caller contract, reverts the state, which is the equivalent to the whole transaction never happening. You can check this in [Solidity's error handling documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions).

If you are directly calling your contract from outside, [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111252/get-the-real-error-of-transaction-failed) may help you debug your call.

Otherwise, if you are calling your contract from another contract, you may wrap the call in a `try/catch` statement, you can see the mechanics in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/control-structures.html#try-catch).